# Ratio test is inclusive; Discuss the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^re^{-k\sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^re^{-k\sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m}}$ when $r > k$ and when $r < k$.

Unfortunately, the ratio test failed. I was trying to use the comparison test instead. My proof is not complete, but I am going to show my work anyway.

> It is not hard to see that $\log(n+1)\le \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m} < 1+\log(n)$. I consider two cases. Assume $k\ge 0$, then
> $k\log(n+1)\le k\sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m} \le (k+1)(1+\log(n))\Rightarrow \frac{n^r}{e^{(k+1)(1+\log(n))}} \le n^re^{-k\sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m}} \le \frac{n^r}{e^{k\log(n+1)}} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n^{k-r+1}} \le n^re^{-k\sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{1}{m}} \le \frac{1}{(n+1)^kn^{-r}}$. From here we can conclude that the original series diverges if $k < r$ and converges if $k -1 > r$. Well, I guess we can say the series converges when $k > k-1 > r$. But I am interested in knowing what happens to the series when $k > r \ge k-1$. I ran into the similar problem when I consider the case $k < 0$.

Looks like I need to use a different approach to solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution used the bounds $$\log(n+1) \le \displaystyle\sum_{m = 1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{m} \le \log(n)+1.$$ It is possible to prove tighter bounds $$\log(n)+\gamma \le \displaystyle\sum_{m = 1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{m} \le \log(n)+\gamma+\dfrac{1}{2n}$$ where $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. If you use these tighter bounds, you'll can bound the series between $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}e^{-k\gamma}n^{r-k}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}e^{-k\gamma-\tfrac{k}{2n}}n^{r-k}$. This will let you determine convergence for all values of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $H_n = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m}$ is asymptotic to $\log n +\gamma$, i.e. $H_n \sim\log n+ \gamma$. Thus, your summand is asymptotically
$$n^r e^{-k\log n}e^{-k\gamma}=n^{r-k}e^{-\gamma k}.$$
Summing over $n$, we see that the series will only converge if $k-r>1$, and will diverge otherwise.